# word extraction from a text file with bash

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

I have a text file similar to the one below :

```
text src=127.0.0.1 text dst=127.0.0.1 text text proto=23
text text text src=192.168.1.254 text text dst=192.168.1.40 text proto=3389
text src=10.213.18.254 text dst=192.168.15.3 text text proto=389
text text text src=192.168.1.254 text text dst=192.168.1.40 text proto=3389
...
```

I want to have an output file (using bash) similar to this one:

```
src=127.0.0.1 dst=127.0.0.1 proto=23
src=192.168.1.254 dst=192.168.1.40 proto=3389
src=10.213.18.254 dst=192.168.15.3 proto=389
src=192.168.1.254 dst=192.168.1.40 proto=3389
```

Unlucky the information's are not always on the same column (and this makes awk useless).  Is there a way with bash to perform this action ?

Comment: Please try an attempt at some code, first, and then try asking about specific problems that appear after that... :)

Comment: wrt `this makes awk useless` - absolutely not true.

Answer (score 4):

In pure bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

# read each line into an array of words
while read -r -a words_in; do

  # copy only words containing '=' into an output array
  words_out=()
  for word in "${words_in[@]}"; do
    [[ $word = *=* ]] && words_out+=( "$word" )
  done

  # use first character of $IFS to join contents of output array when printing.
  printf '%s\n' "${words_out[*]}"
done
```

If you want a different criteria, modifying the content of the inner loop should be straightforward. For instance, to only pass through words starting with `src=`, `dst=` or `proto=`:

```
  for word in "${words_in[@]}"; do
    case $word in
      src=*|dst=*|proto=*) words_out+=( "$word" ) ;;
    esac
  done
```

Comment: +1. I like this approach. But two questions for you. 1) `while read -r -a words_in ; do `  should be enough to avoid to use REPLY then set array words-in directly. 2) `[[ $word =~ = ]]` should be better and one letter shorter.  :-)

Comment: @BMW Heh -- using read twice was, indeed, a thinko on my part. As for `=~`, it's a more recent feature (3.0, IIRC, but with unstable semantics until 3.1 or 3.2?), so the extra character to use glob-style patterns is slightly better for compatibility.

Comment: got it.  No questions now.

Answer (score 4):

Any time you have input data that contains `name=value` pairs, consider creating an array to map the field names on the left of each `=` with their values on the right, then just printing the fields by name:

```
$ awk '{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        split($i,t,/=/)
        map[t[1]] = t[2]
    }
    print "src="map["src"], "dst="map["dst"], "proto="map["proto"]
}' file
src=127.0.0.1 dst=127.0.0.1 proto=23
src=192.168.1.254 dst=192.168.1.40 proto=3389
src=10.213.18.254 dst=192.168.15.3 proto=389
src=192.168.1.254 dst=192.168.1.40 proto=3389
```

You can add a function to simplify and remove redundancy from the printing if you like:

```
$ awk 'function m(str) { return(str"="map[str]) }
{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        split($i,t,/=/)
        map[t[1]] = t[2]
    }
    print m("src"), m("dst"), m("proto")
}' file
src=127.0.0.1 dst=127.0.0.1 proto=23
src=192.168.1.254 dst=192.168.1.40 proto=3389
src=10.213.18.254 dst=192.168.15.3 proto=389
src=192.168.1.254 dst=192.168.1.40 proto=3389
```

Comment: +1: Elegant as always. Your solution makes me realize how much I need to improve in `awk`. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Using sed

```
sed 's/text\s//g' filename
```

Comment: I'm assuming `text` to be a placeholder for anything not containing an `=` character. But, granted, it would be nice if the question were more clear.

Comment: I assumed he wants all `text` removed

Comment: That *is* the literalist answer, yes. However, in context, this is almost certainly firewall, tcpdump, or wireshark logs, none of which include literal `text`.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` can do this without any problem.

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/=[0-9]/) printf "%s ",$i;print ""}' file
src=127.0.0.1 dst=127.0.0.1 proto=23
src=192.168.1.254 dst=192.168.1.40 proto=3389
src=10.213.18.254 dst=192.168.15.3 proto=389
src=192.168.1.254 dst=192.168.1.40 proto=3389
```

This prints all fields that does contains `=` and a number behind.

---

Another version:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/(src|dst|proto)=/) printf "%s ",$i;print ""}' file
src=127.0.0.1 dst=127.0.0.1 proto=23
src=192.168.1.254 dst=192.168.1.40 proto=3389
src=10.213.18.254 dst=192.168.15.3 proto=389
src=192.168.1.254 dst=192.168.1.40 proto=3389
```

This prints any field that does contains `src=` or `dst=` or `proto=`

---

This removes an extra space that gets behind the last data in above solution:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/(src|dst|proto)=/) s=s" "$i;sub(/ /,"",s);print s;s=""}' file
```

---

Even another way to do it with `awk` without using loop:

```
awk 's {printf s"="$1($NF=="src"?"\n":FS);s=0} {s=$NF}' RS="=" file
src=127.0.0.1 dst=127.0.0.1 proto=23
src=192.168.1.254 dst=192.168.1.40 proto=3389
src=10.213.18.254 dst=192.168.15.3 proto=389
src=192.168.1.254 dst=192.168.1.40 proto=3389
```

This breaks every line by the `=` and take parts needed to create new line.

Comment: +1; for large inputs, this will certainly be faster than the pure-bash solution.